# Change page dimensions (orientation) within open device

Tags: r

Is it possible to change the dimensions of a page as I'm writing to an open device?  For example, lets say I'm writing to PDF in "portrait" orientation (8.5in wide x 11 in height) and at some point I want a page in "landscape" orientation (11in wide x 8.5 in high).  The original orientation is set in the pdf(...) call.  Can that be modified so that a call to grid.new or plot() (where there are no more plot regions available and a new page is required) results in a different orientation?

Comment: Would post processing (merging of several pdfs) be a viable option?

Comment: Probably a lot easier to post-process w/ some pdf tool, i.e. write to several files and merge them outside of R.  Or if you have any decent command-line pdf tools, like `pdftk` or `pdftex` , call them from R.

Comment: Edit :  package `animation` has a wrapper for pdftk.

Comment: Roman, Carl - My preference is avoid post-processing.  I have a vague recollection of getting this to work with an open PDF device in the past, but it was an accident and not the purpose of my work at the time so I didn't record what I did. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to do this.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use LaTeX to place the various graphics within a multipage pdf (e.g. pgfSweave with tikzDevice, say). The landscape package allows you to switch one page to landscape format.

Comment: baptiste - In this scenario I'm wondering if its possible without LaTeX